# What features does visual studio have to help debug compile time errors in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

Compile time errors in C++ are one of my banes. What tricks, tips and features can help me become better at debugging these?

Comment: Write error free code, which requires practice, should be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 has introduced [Squiggles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/06/01/c-gets-squiggles.aspx). This will help a lot with obvious compile-time errors.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the STLFilt tool:
http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html

It will nicely format your STL-related compile errors into a human-readable form. It's not always perfect, but it really makes a life easier. Take a look at this output comparison, for example: http://www.bdsoft.com/dist/vcmeta-demo.txt